# Why does Spring Security demand password for permitAll() url?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Here is URL I want to access
`http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html`.

Here is my Security config, both h2-console and swagger url and accesible only with password.

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers(req -> req.getRequestURI().contains("admin")).hasAuthority(Role.ADMIN.getAuthority())
                .antMatchers("/h2-console/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/index.html").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .headers().frameOptions().disable()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }
```

Comment: Did you try with just `http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/h2-console/").permitAll().antMatchers("/swagger-ui/index.html").permitAll()` ? Is it working?

Comment: You are just allowing the `/swagger-ui/index.html` file, are you sure that swagger doesn't load any other resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my app, i have this configuration which works for me...

```
 private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = {
    // -- swagger ui
    "/swagger-resources/**",
    "/swagger-ui",
    "/swagger-ui/",
    "/swagger-ui/**",
    "/v2/api-docs",
    "/webjars/**"
  };

 @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll()
      .anyRequest().authenticated()
      .and()
      .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
      .and()
      .logout();
  }
```